# UI unresponsive + progress bar not working while using backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application in Visual Studio, I need to download a large file and extract it in my code. Someone recommended that I use background workers, but now when I try to increase the value on my progress bar it doesn't work... Can anyone help?

```
public void InstallVersion(string version)
    {
        string location = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\MidnightFallsLauncher\data\locator.txt");
        location = location + @"\Versions\" + version;

        if (File.Exists(location + ".zip"))
            File.Delete(location + ".zip");

        if (Directory.Exists(location))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(location);

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                dir.Delete(true);
             }
        }


        if (!myWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            myWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

And here is my worker code

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(myWorker_DoWork);
        myWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        myWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(myWorker_ProgressChanged);
        myWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        myWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    protected void myWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        string location = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Roaming\MidnightFallsLauncher\data\locator.txt");
        location = location + @"\Versions\" + Version;

        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        string url = "";
        string content = "";
        string downloadlink = "";

        List<string> availibleVersions = new List<string>();
        List<string> versionDownload = new List<string>();

        url = "https://midnightfalls.glitch.me/versions.html";
        content = Client.DownloadString(url);

        foreach (string line in content.Split(new string[] { "<br>", "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            if (line.Contains("0"))
            {
                availibleVersions.Add(line);
            }

        }

        url = "https://midnightfalls.glitch.me/versionslink.html";
        content = Client.DownloadString(url);

        foreach (string line in content.Split(new string[] { "<br>", "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            if (line.Contains("https"))
            {
                versionDownload.Add(line);
            }

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < availibleVersions.Count; i++)
        {
            if (availibleVersions[i] == Version)
            {
                downloadlink = versionDownload[i];
            }
        }


        Client.DownloadFile(downloadlink, location + ".zip");

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(location + ".zip", location);
        File.Delete(location + ".zip");

        RunGame(Version);
    }

    protected void myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void myWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            progress.Value += 10;
        });
    }
```

Also, while my worker is running, the UI freezes... I'm pretty sure that's not meant to happen.

**EDIT:**
The UI is now updating but the progress bar still doesnt work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the main thread is constantly working while the background worker is doing its work:

```
 while (this.myWorker.IsBusy)
 {
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        progress.Value += 10;
    });
}
```

means that your main thread is constantly doing stuff while the background job is working, which is why the UI doesn't update.

You need to move the progress update to the background worker (where you could also set a value that actually makes some sense, e.g. to indicate how many of the 'availableVersion's you have downloaded).

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

Suppose we'll put all the code directly in the view, so assume we have a progress bar named 'progressBar' and a button named 'btnStart' (which kicks of the backgroundworker).

Here's the codebehind:

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;

 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    this.worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(myWorker_DoWork);
    this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new 
    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    this.worker.ProgressChanged += new 
    ProgressChangedEventHandler(myWorker_ProgressChanged);
    this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

private void myWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void myWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     // Whatever you need to do when finished here (alert, update a label, etc.)
}

private void myWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Just loop and report new progress. Sleep a little in between each
    // progress update so that it isn't over before we have a chance to see it.
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        this.worker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

What happens is that the background worker fires an event notifying that progress has changed. 
The main thread has a handle on that event, and updates the progress bar. 
Since it's a background worker you don't need to use Dispatcher.Invoke - this is already taken care of.

Hope the example clarifies things for you.

Comment: You're welcome. Is the code in the question the updated code? Or did you move the update of progress to the background worker?
Also, have you seen the comment I made on the other answer?

Comment: Ok, you're not actually updating the progress in your worker. I'll edit my post with a small working example.

Comment: No worries. I'll add that, like Daniel Mann mentioned, you should look into the async await pattern if you're running a newer version of .NET (>=4.5). It really makes things a lot easier and the code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're blocking right here:

```
while (this.myWorker.IsBusy)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        progress.Value += 10;
    });
}
```

You should be calling `ReportProgress` on your `BackgroundWorker` instance within your `myWorker_DoWork` method.

Also, if you're using .NET 4.5 or later, you can dump the `BackgroundWorker` entirely and rewrite this code using the `async`/`await` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, it unfreezes the UI but the progress bar still isnt changing

Comment: You might be adding to the value too frequently. In your original code, you'd reach a progress value of 100 straight away, which would mean it can never change from that. 
Also make sure you're not invoking it too frequently, which would mean that you're still blocking the UI thread by forcing it to do work.

Comment: @WhoKnows On Stack Overflow, once your original question is answered, you should accept an answer and then ask a new question if you have another problem.